# In a 4 node cluster, how do we install Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a 4  node cluster of 1 name node and 3 data nodes. I need to install Hive. Should i install Hive on all the nodes or only the name node. 
If Hive is installed on all the machines, Then how does it work when we access from a data node?

Comment: Install just on one node and update hive configuration with your job tracker and dfs properties.

Answer (score 1):

Hive can be installed in any machine. Hive only dependency is hadoop installation similar to your cluster. Hive needs Hadoop installation path to figure out location of Job tracker e.t.c. You can copy the hadoop installation from cluster to you local machine and then install Hive on your local box.

Lets say you have installed Hive on one of the data node and hive is pointing to the hadoop installation. Now when you execute a Query in Hive, Hive will convert your query into one or more Map Reduce program and then it will submit this programs to Hadoop's Job Tracker. Job Tracker then executes this map reduce program.